# Powershell - Pip freeze inside virtual environment listing packages from global pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, python-3.6

I'm not sure if I set up this venv wrong or what

This is how I created it :

```
python -m venv venv
```

Entering it :

```
venv/Scripts/activate
```

And then pip freeze :

```
(venv) pip freeze
```

I've tried pip3, pip3.6, pip, they all give me the list from global pip, I only want the list of installed packages inside the venv, how to do it?

Comment: try `python -m pip freeze` inside venv

Comment: I think the problem is that the venv is using global python

Comment: Does it happen if you run `env/bin/pip freeze`? That should force venv to use its own pip.

Comment: @Dash that works, yeah, I think activate.bat is not settings the variables correctly somehow

Comment: Whats the output of `type -a python`?

Comment: Also, is this on linux or windows?

Comment: windows, sorry forgot the tag

Comment: I think it has something to do with powershell, it seems to be working on a regular cmd