# pip-list inside and outside environment give the same list

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

My question is very similar to this one : [Powershell - Pip freeze inside virtual environment listing packages from global pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56811800/powershell-pip-freeze-inside-virtual-environment-listing-packages-from-global)

I'm developing a Django app. I suspect that despite having a virtual environment activated by

`$ source env_dir/bin/activate`

I'm still working with the global system Python environment: `pip-list` (or `python3 -m pip-list`) give the same output whether or not the environment is activated. Same thing with `pip freeze` / `python3 pip freeze`.

How could I be sure of it, and fix this if necessary?

Edit : Developing under Linux Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Did you activate it using `venv/Scripts/activate.bat` or `venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`? The former works with CMD but the latter is for Powershell. The former does not properly activate an environment when used in Powershell

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I was under Ubuntu! Editing the original post right now.

Comment: Oh. Can you edit the question to include the commands you used to create the environment and what you are using to activate it? Do you get `(env_dir)` added to your bash prompt?

Comment: Yes (env_dir) is displayed at prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have same modules installed in global as well as virtual environment. Now you can try to install a module in global env and check if it still is the same.

Use `sudo pip install <package name>` to install it in global env.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Atul. When I install a module inside the env, then deactivate, then pip list, the module still appears as installed...